# how to insert the data from the first table to the second table to be like this example

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I am using codeigniter and mysql, i have two tables .
the first table name "checkinout":
the second table name "check_times":

table_name:"checkinout"

```
----------------------------------------------------------------------------
user_id  | date         | time
----------------------------------------------------------------------------
 3       |  2014-09-30  | 05:40:35,06:40:35,09:40:35,12:40:35
 3       |  2014-10-01  | 05:40:35,10:30:35
 2       |  2014-11-22  | 07:00:35
```

---

i want to insert the data from the first table to the second table to 
be like this:
table_name:"check_times"

```
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
user_id  | date         | in_1       | out_1      | in_2       | out_2 
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 3       |  2014-09-30  |  05:40:35  |  06:40:35  |  09:40:35  |  12:40:35 
 3       |  2014-10-01  |  05:40:35  |  10:30:35  |            |
 2       |  2014-11-22  |  07:00:35  |            |            |
```

==============================================================================
I tried using explode() function but it show an error message for each empty value.

My model name is "test_model"
This is my model function

```
public function get_data()
{
    $query = $this->db->get('checkinout')->result();
    foreach ($query as $result)
    {
        if($result->check_time)
        {
            $result->check_time = explode(",", $result->check_time);
        }
    }
    return $query;
}
```

My controller name is "test"
This is my controller function

```
public function show()
{
    $query = $this->test_model->get_data();
    foreach ($query as $row)
    {
        $data['results'] = array
        (
            'userid' => $row->userid ,
            'check_date' => $row->check_date , 
            'in_1' =>$row->check_time[0] ,
            'out_1' =>$row->check_time[1] ,
            'in_2' =>$row->check_time[2] ,
            'out_2' =>$row->check_time[3]
        );
        $this->load->view('test_view',$data);
    }
}
```

My view name is "test_view"

```
echo "<pre>";
print_r($results);
```

The result is

```
A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Notice

Message: Undefined offset: 2

Filename: controllers/test.php

Line Number: 50

A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Notice

Message: Undefined offset: 3

Filename: controllers/test.php

Line Number: 51
A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Notice

Message: Undefined offset: 1

Filename: controllers/test.php

Line Number: 49
A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Notice

Message: Undefined offset: 2

Filename: controllers/test.php

Line Number: 50
A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Notice

Message: Undefined offset: 3

Filename: controllers/test.php

Line Number: 51


Array
(
[userid] => 3
[check_date] => 2014-09-30
[in_1] => 12:40:35
[out_1] => 09:40:35
[in_2] => 06:40:35
[out_2] => 05:40:35
)
Array
(
[userid] => 3
[check_date] => 2014-10-01
[in_1] => 10:30:35
[out_1] => 05:40:35
[in_2] => 
[out_2] => 
)
Array
(
[userid] => 2
[check_date] => 2014-11-22
[in_1] => 07:00:35
[out_1] => 
[in_2] => 
[out_2] =>
```

## )

My controller after modification

```
public function show()
{
    $query=$this->test_model->get_data();
    foreach ($query as $row)
    {
        $data['results'] = array();
        $data['results']['userid']= $row->userid ;
        $data['results']['check_date'] = $row->check_date ;

        if(isset($row->check_time[0]))
        {$data['results']['in_1']  = $row->check_time[0] ;}
        else{$data['results']['in_1']  = '00:00:00' ;}

        if(isset($row->check_time[1]))
        {$data['results']['out_1'] = $row->check_time[1] ;}
        else{$data['results']['out_1']  = '00:00:00' ;}

        if(isset($row->check_time[2]))
        {$data['results']['in_2']  = $row->check_time[2] ;}
        else{$data['results']['in_2']  = '00:00:00' ;}

        if(isset($row->check_time[3]))
        {$data['results']['out_2'] = $row->check_time[3] ;}
        else{$data['results']['out_2']  = '00:00:00' ;}

        $this->load->view('test_view',$data);
    }
}
```

Thanks for all, Now it is good

Comment: Are there going to be `in_3`, `out_3`, etc. as well?

Comment: No only in_1,out_1 , in_2,out_2

Comment: 1. Stop. 2. See normalization

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just get the field `time` from `checkinout` table, use the [`explode()`](http://php.net/manual/es/function.explode.php) function and prepair the insert on `check_times`

Comment: I tried using explode() function but it show an error message for each empty value.

Comment: I tried but I get the same error message, Can you explain more how can i do this?

Comment: Thanks very much!! I modified my controller function and added the condition. Now the result become good without any error message